# Primefaces Schedule not rendering event background color on Month View

Tags: primefaces, fullcalendar

In day or week view all the event colors are right colored, but in month view none. As I could saw in HTML, in month view, all events don't have the fc-bg div (responsable for coloring).

Schedule:

```
 <p:schedule id="agendaOcupacional" allDaySlot="false" slotLabelFormat="HH:mm" widgetVar="myAgendaOcupacional" class="agenda" tooltip="true"
                                draggable="false" resizable="false" timeZone="GMT-3" extender="initSchedule" slotEventOverlap="false" minTime="07:30:00" maxTime="19:00:00"
                                showWeekends="false" view="agendaDay" slotDuration="00:15:00" value="#{agendamentoBean.eventModel}" locale="br"  >
                        <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{agendamentoBean.onDateSelect}" oncomplete="PF('myAgendaOcupacional').update()"/>
                        <p:ajax event="eventSelect" listener="#{agendamentoBean.onEventSelect}" onstart="PF('statusDialog').show()" onsuccess="PF('statusDialog').hide()"/>
                    </p:schedule>
```

Extender:

```
function initSchedule() {
                            this.cfg.views = {
                                day: {
                                    displayEventTime: false,
                                    slotLabelInterval: 15
                                },
                                week: {
                                    slotLabelInterval: 15,
                                    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
                                    titleFormat: "dddd DD / MMMM",
                                    columnFormat: "dddd - DD/MM"
                                },
                                month: {
                                    displayEventTime: true,
                                    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
                                    slotLabelInterval: 15
                                }
                            };
                        }
```

A part from Lazy Init for Schedule (here "atendido" and "emergencial" are responsable to color my events in the schedule):

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    if (list.get(i).isAtendidoDiretamente() == false && list.get(i).getTipoAgendamento() == 1
                            && list.get(i).isReagendado() == false && list.get(i).isCancelado() == false) {
                        if (list.get(i).isEmergencial() == true && list.get(i).isAtendido() == false) {
                            if (list.get(i).getPaciente().getId() == 9999998) {
                                event = new DefaultScheduleEvent(list.get(i).getPaciente().getNome(),
                                        list.get(i).getId().getDataAgendamento().getTime(), list.get(i).getHorarioFinal().getTime(), "emergencial");
                                eventModel.addEvent(event);
                            } else {
                                event = new DefaultScheduleEvent(list.get(i).getPaciente().getNome() + " - " + list.get(i).getPaciente().getCartaoPonto(),
                                        list.get(i).getId().getDataAgendamento().getTime(), list.get(i).getHorarioFinal().getTime(), "emergencial");
                                eventModel.addEvent(event);
                            }
                        } else if (list.get(i).isAtendido()) {
                            event = new DefaultScheduleEvent(list.get(i).getPaciente().getNome() + " - " + list.get(i).getPaciente().getCartaoPonto(),
                                    list.get(i).getId().getDataAgendamento().getTime(), list.get(i).getHorarioFinal().getTime(), "atendido");
                            eventModel.addEvent(event);
```

If I set in my extender `eventBackgroundColor: "red"` in month view, then the event receive style="background-color: red". Month view only have fc-content div, different than month/day, which have both fc-content and fc-bg. I think this can be a bug.

Searching in FullCalendar directly there is no option to set true or false for rendering event color in different view's.

I'm using Primefaces 7.0.

Comment: It's not a bug that the different views have different divs with different classes. They are rendered completely differently because of the different layouts. But anyway you should not be relying on the HTML structure to set the background colour. Instead it's the responsibility of each event object to set its own background colour (or you can do it per event-source, if you prefer). fullCalendar will then take the background colour specified in the event object and render it correctly, regardless of which view is being used. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object

Comment: In Primefaces, you have the DefaultScheduleEvent(String title, Date start, Date end, String styleClass) method, which I use in my code (responsable for week and day coloring). But using this method do not color Month view. I'm not saying that FullCalendar is bugged, I'm saying that Primefaces is.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately I don't know anything about primefaces or what it does, I just know about base fullCalendar, so I probably can't help you further, sorry

Comment: The PrimeFaces source is open. Easy to debug and see what happens with the styleclass in month view

Comment: @ADyson thank you anyway ADyson.

Comment: @Kukeltje I'm a new developer, never debug some external project before, but i will search how to, thank you.

Comment: @RogerAlves if you think this is a bug or an issue with PrimeFaces, you can submit the Issue to the PrimeFaces github https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues